# Open md-select programatically from controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a scenario where I need to open the md-select box based on certain condition on page load. I checked the doumentation [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect) but there is no such option mentioned in the API.

Any inputs/links for achieving this are appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: u can use `ng-if` directive to check the condition in your select box

Comment: Ng-if is fine to show or hide the elements but the question is about which property to use to open the select box programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

In a code that I wrote a few weeks ago (http://codepen.io/nadeemramsing/pen/EgdqLg), I used ng-init and ng-selected to set a default value on page load.

```
<md-select ng-model="vm.selectedCountry" ng-init="vm.selectedCountry = vm.selectedCountry?vm.selectedCountry : 'CH';">

                <md-option ng-value="'CH'" ng-selected="vm.selectedCountry == 'CH'?true:false">Switzerland</md-option>

                <md-option ng-repeat="country in vm.countries" ng-value="country.code">
                    {{country.name}}
                </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: I am looking to open the select box for the user, not to select the option on load. Any idea sind that?